# Add methods to RelatedManager

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use the following property to access a ordered queryset from templates:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    @property
    def descending_choice_set(self):
        """
        Order choice_set by votes descending.
        """
        return self.choice_set.order_by('-votes')
```

But I would prefer to access it by `question.choice_set.order_by_votes` instead of `question.descending_choice_set`. For this behavior the `RelatedManager` must be overridden. How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom manager and put all methods like `order_by_votes` into it. Here is an example:

```
from django.db import models

class ChoiceManager(models.Manager):
  def order_by_votes(self):
    return self.order_by('-vote_number')

# Create your models here.
class Choice(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  vote_number = models.IntegerField()

  # register your manager. You literally can put any variable name here. 
  # Just do not forget to access manager through it later :)
  objects = ChoiceManager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Usage:

```
In [1]: from app import models
In [2]: c = models.Choice.objects.create(name='first', vote_number=1)
In [3]: c = models.Choice.objects.create(name='second', vote_number=2)
In [4]: models.Choice.objects.order_by_votes()
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<Choice: second>, <Choice: first>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Taras said, you could write a custom manager. But writing a custom manager will only allow the method to be called for the model itself.
Inorder to override related manager methods, you need to use the setting `use_for_related_fields`.

Setting `use_for_related_fields` to True on the manager will make it available on all relations that point to the model on which you defined this manager as the default manager. This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-types)

```
class MyManager(models.Manager)
    use_for_related_fields = True # ...

    def order_by_votes(self):
        return self.order_by('-vote_number')
```

Write a custom manager for the model and set the above setting to True. I'd recommend write the managers for both Question and Choice models for better functionality and add the setting.

Comment: Looks like this was [deprecated](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/290) a while back.